# take sum of last 7 days from the observed date in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table on which I want to compute the sum of revenue on last 7 days from the observed day. Here is my table -

```
with temp as 
(
select DATE('2019-06-29') as transaction_date, "x"as id, 0 as revenue
union all
select DATE('2019-06-30') as transaction_date, "x"as id,  80 as revenue
union all
select DATE('2019-07-04') as transaction_date, "x"as id, 64 as revenue
union all
select DATE('2019-07-06') as transaction_date, "x"as id, 64 as revenue
union all
select DATE('2019-07-11') as transaction_date, "x"as id, 75 as revenue
union all
select DATE('2019-07-12') as transaction_date, "x"as id, 0 as revenue
)


select * from temp
```

I want to take a sum of last 7 days for each `transaction_date`. For instance for the last record which has `transaction_date = 2019-07-12`, I would like to add another column which adds up `revenue` for last 7 days from `2019-07-12` (which is until `2019-07-05`), hence the value of new `rollup_revenue` column would be `0 + 75 + 64 = 139`. Likewise, I need to compute the rollup for all the dates for every ID.

Note - the ID may or may not appear daily.

I have tried self join but I am unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  SUM(revenue) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(transaction_date) 
    RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) rollup_revenue 
FROM `project.dataset.temp`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.temp` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-06-29' AS transaction_date, 'x' AS id, 0 AS revenue UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-06-30', 'x', 80 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-04', 'x', 64 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-06', 'x', 64 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-11', 'x', 75 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-07-12', 'x', 0
)
SELECT *, 
  SUM(revenue) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(transaction_date) 
    RANGE BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
  ) rollup_revenue 
FROM `project.dataset.temp`
-- ORDER BY transaction_date
```

with result

```sql
Row transaction_date    id  revenue rollup_revenue   
1   2019-06-29          x   0       0    
2   2019-06-30          x   80      80   
3   2019-07-04          x   64      144  
4   2019-07-06          x   64      208  
5   2019-07-11          x   75      139  
6   2019-07-12          x   0       139
```

Comment: Doesn't this compute the sum of the preceding 7 _records_, which may not be coincident with the actual 7 preceding _days_?

Comment: nice approach, dunno can solve by unix_date with range

Comment: thank you for the answer. Quick question about `ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(transaction_date) ` .. can we not do `order by transaction_date` and get the same results ?

Comment: No. we cannot. This Ordering is important to make sure we do SUM for last 6 days

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a correlated subquery to find the rolling sum:

```
SELECT
    transaction_date,
    revenue,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.revenue) FROM temp t2 WHERE t2.transaction_date
         BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.transaction_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
                                       t1.transaction_date) AS rev_7_days
FROM temp t1
ORDER BY
   transaction_date;
```